# What are the differences between probabilistic models, stochastic models, and statistical models?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, modeling, stochastic-processes

What are the differences between probabilistic models, stochastic models, and statistical models?

Do statistical models deal with data sets, and model them mathematically to capture the summary statistics of the data set or population?

Do stochastic models represent random processes?

Do probabilistic models represent transitions in state machines or automata with probabilistic transitions?

Comment: I doubt any of these terms have universally agreed-on meanings.  Do you have some references or definitions you can supply?